# Google Mobile Ads Bidding mediation issues in ad inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am testing my mediation bidding with Google Admob, but I am getting the below errors for each of the bidding networks participating. Google Mobile Ads in Unity is updated to the latest version.
Has anyone had a similar issue before?
[mobile ads inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3OL8.jpg)

I tried updating the Google Mobile Ads to the latest version but it still does not work

Comment: what errors you havent shown any

Comment: as you can see in the image attached above on the link, I get error "No user consent provided"

Comment: problem is solved. the Admob now requires GDPR consent from EU countries. Also for the missing SDK adapters, I needed to update to the latest ones for Admob